# Passing parameter with PromptDialog.Confirm:resume Bot Framework (C#)

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

Before showing Prompt Confirmation Dialog, am getting some inputs from the user. Based on those inputs and PromptDialog (Yes/No) selection, I have to do some functional logic.
**Prompt Dialog**

```
PromptDialog.Confirm(
           context: context,
           resume: ServiceDetails,
           prompt: "Shall I continue with " + facility,
           retry: "Please,Confirm?.");
```

**Resume Function: ServiceDetails**

```
 private async Task ServiceDetails(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> result)
    {
        var confirm = await result;
        if (confirm && facility=="xxx") // They said yes
        {
```

In ServiceDetails method,I have to pass "facility" value. Is it possible? or Should I use session(context.userdata.SetValue) for this particular conversation to get "facility" value?

Comment: The callback is only going to have the extra `bool` parameter, anything else will have to go in the context data.

Comment: @jackarms yes, only by context data I able to get value, that is context.userdata.SetValue. But in bot framework its like session.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, one option would be to use the Bot Data Bags and store the values there. I think that it might makes more sense to use the PrivateConversationData data bag instead of the UserData as the latter will be available across all the channels and conversations. You can see more about this in the [State sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-State).

Another alternative, that could be more suitable depending on your workflow, is to use FormFlow. With FormFlow you can define a model that later will be translated into questions. Once the form is completed you will get the "state" of the form with all the answers provided by the user.

[Here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html) you can find the documentation around FormFlow. And [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs/Dialogs/HotelsDialog.cs#L19) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers/Dialogs/RootDialog.cs#L142) some examples on how can be used.

Comment: getting two inputs from query entity. based on the entity questions should ask. If I use single formflow `IForm<GetFacilityQuery> BuildFacilityForm()` how can I check set value and `field.active` for those inputs.

Comment: Not fully following you but it seems a different question from the one in this thread. I would recommend to open a new question with this inquiry

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class-level variable,`facility` and then do `this.facility=facility` in your functional logic Prompt Dialog.

You could then read this value in ServiceDetails simply as `this.facility=="xxx"`